# Is there anyway i'm able to make a block (a variable) not have to reset its position and carry on?

Tags: css

I recently have been trying out CSS to test somethings for my loading panel but i've had some difficulties making the spinner go completely around.. it's a pretty simple code but sadly it has an annoying issue.. When attempting to make it rotating around its center axis it decides that when it gets to 360° it will restart and go back to 0° instead of carrying on to 0°, Im sorry if its a bit hard to understand but basically it takes a full 240° turn instead of just a 90° to make it restart.
Heres the code,

```
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
    10% {
     transform: rotate(40deg)
    }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(80deg)
  }
    30% {
    transform: rotate(120deg)
    }
    40% {
    transform: rotate(160deg)
    }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(200deg)
  }
    60% {
    transform: rotate(240deg)
    }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(280deg)
  }
    80% {
    transform: rotate(320deg)

    }
    90% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-0deg)     
  }
}
```

As you might be able to see it rotates to 360° but then fails to **carry on** to 0° and takes it all the way back to 0deg.. any ways to help/fix?

Thanks,

-David

Comment: Can you provide all of your code so we have a working demo of what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can just stop the animation at 360deg and it stops and doesn't go back. 360deg is a full rotation. No need to "return" to 0.

```css
img {
  animation: spin 2s infinite;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(40deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(80deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(120deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(160deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(200deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(240deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(280deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(320deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://images.gawker.com/twtjebkms5hvjr0wiinh/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800.jpg">
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want michael, I was going to upload my entire code but I would like it to repeat, which I have it setup to do,   `animation: loader-inner 8000s infinite ease-in;' where I want it to infinitely repeat.

Comment: It decided to fix itself! Thanks for the help all, I dont know what i did but I think it might be due to something what you said, Thanks anyway.